# Error while deleting a list in the IntelliJ console

Tags: python, intellij-idea

```
> with open("albums.txt", "r") as albums:
>     mylist = []
>     for line in albums:
>         # data row should consist of (artist, album, year, song)
>         artist_field, album_field, year_field, song_field = tuple(line.strip('\n').split('\t'))
>         year_field = int(year_field)
>         mylist.append((artist_field, album_field, year_field, song_field))
>     song_list = []
>     for i in [5, 10, 26, 28, 41]:
>         song_list.append(mylist[i])
> 
> del mylist 
print(song_list)
```

I try to delete `mylist` but I see an error only in the console and not when it runs. It seems like it is deleted, and I don't see any problem with the program. Maybe I don't understand the error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\G\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py",
> line 241, in frame_vars_to_struct
> v = frame_f_locals[k] KeyError: 'mylist' Unexpected error, recovered safely.

Comment: Looks like an IDE bug. Which Python version do you use? I cannot reproduce it on my side.

Comment: when you remove `del mylist` what do you get ?

Comment: @D.L
No, i dont

Comment: @Gaff,  can you confirm that you still see the error ?